# BlueJ (How to give a String value in if else)

Tags: java, string

What is wrong in this program?

I wanted to create a program that will open only when password is put.
It is not accepting the String value as password. So can any one modify it??

```
import java.io.*;

class aa

{

    public static void main(String input)throws IOException
    {
        String a;
        if(a.equals("A"))
        {
            InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
            double x;
            double y;
            double z;
            System.out.println("Please type the two Numbers");
            x=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            y=Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
            z=x*y;
            System.out.println("Product="+z);
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `a.equals()` is used when `a` is uninitialized. Initialize it before using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String a;
if(a.equals("A"))
{
  ...
  ...
}
```

You havent assigned any values to your variable a. Hence, it never enters the if loop . Try this:

```
String a;
InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
a = in.ReadLine();    
if(a.equals("A"))        
{
      ...
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code to read strings to read strings.

example:

```
public static void main(String input)throws IOException
{
    String a;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // add this line
    a = br.readLine(); // add this line
    if(a.equals("A"))
    {
```

or if you mean to use the `input`:

```
public static void main(String input)throws IOException
{
    String a;
    a = input; // add this line
    if(a.equals("A"))
    {
```

Note: this `main` method is *not* an entry point because signature of entry points are `public static void main(String[] args)` and signature of this function differs from this because the argument is not an array but a string.